# Ansible playbook group_var being overriden by a role var

Tags: vagrant, ansible

For an existing project, I am replacing a bash provision script with ansible -- through Vagrant first, and then rolling it out for staging/prod servers after the kinks are worked out.

### The problem...

According to the [ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) on variable precedence, group_vars should override role vars, but I'm seeing the opposite happen.

### The relevant files...

Following is an excerpt from my `Vagrantfile` (in the project root):

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "app/config/provision/provision.yml"
end
```

I am pointing it to a playbook a few subdirectories down, as I'm working in an existing codebase with its own practices, and can't leave the ansible stuff cluttering up the root. The playbook in question:

```
# app/config/provision/provision.yml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  sudo: true

  roles:
    - apache
    - php

  post_tasks:
    - debug: var=vagrant_ansible_test_loading_vars
    - debug: var=apache_listen_ports
```

Note the debug statements for two vars, both of which are defined in a group_vars file alongside the playbook:

```
# app/config/provision/group_vars/all
---
vagrant_ansible_test_loading_vars: "lorem ipsum"

apache_listen_ports:
  - 80
  - 8080
```

The apache role I'm using defines defaults (which should have the LOWEST precedence):

```
# app/config/provision/roles/apache/defaults/main.yml
---
apache_listen_ports: [ 80, 8080 ]
```

That same role also defines vars (which should be SECOND lowest precedence):

```
# app/config/provision/roles/apache/vars/main.yml
---
apache_listen_ports: [ 80 ]
```

### The (unexpected) result

And yet, upon `vagrant up`, I'm getting this:

```
TASK: [debug var=vagrant_ansible_test_loading_vars] *************************** 
ok: [default] => {
    "vagrant_ansible_test_loading_vars": "lorem ipsum"
}

TASK: [debug var=apache_listen_ports] ***************************************** 
ok: [default] => {
    "apache_listen_ports": [
        80
    ]
}
```

The first variable being defined and having its original value tells me that my group_vars file *is* being loaded. The second variable has been overridden from the group_vars value, with (apparently) the value from the role vars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables in roles/rolename/vars/main.yml are VERY high priority. They are considered constants and cannot be overridden without modifying the role. roles/rolename/defaults/main.yml are low priority and are just that--defaults that can be easily overridden.